# How to extract specific part of a line in a text in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a huge file that I splitted in a series of lines with the function `text.splitlines()`. From these lines I need to specifically extract some informations corresponding to a keyword: "ref-p". What I did is:

```
for index, line in enumerate(tpr_linee):
    ref = "ref-p"
    a = []
    if ref in line:

        a.append(line)

        print(a)
```

what I obtained is:

```
  1  ['   ref-p (3x3):']
  2  ['      ref-p[    0]={ 1.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00}']
  3  ['      ref-p[    1]={ 0.00000e+00,  1.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00}']
  4  ['      ref-p[    2]={ 0.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00,  1.00000e+00}']
```

now I need to move the three series of number into a dictionary in the form:

`{ref-p: [[number, number, number], [number, number, number], etc]}`.

Also, in the larger dataset the array 3x3 may be a different shape in different files.

So my main goal is to find a way to extract all the numbers corresponding to `ref-p`, taking only the numbers and ignoring the first appearance of `ref-p` key.

Comment: This doesn't look like there will be any magic trick you can do, you'll have to pick apart the file into its pieces and then assemble the data structure. You might use regular expressions and/or the `split()` method. You'll need to work through the file piece by piece, keeping track of relevant information and partial structures in variables as you go along.

Comment: This is one of those "more tedious than clever" situations...

Comment: @ScottHunter the code and output are exactly how I run the code and what I obtain as output

Comment: @JiříBaum unfortunately I was thinking the same but I can't come out with a solution to this

Comment: @ScottHunter the print(a) is just to show you what I should include in the dictionary. It will not be in the final code

Comment: Why do you `a = []` at the start of each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited the first part of your code, so that the list `a` will contain a list of strings to be analysed.

Then I split each string based on "=" (equal) sign, and strip the curly braces "{" and "}" to extract only the string of numbers.

When converting to float, the numbers are just 0.0 and 1.0. Try this:

```
a = []
for index, line in enumerate(tpr_linee):
    if 'ref-p' in line:
        a.append(line)
print(a)

a = ['   ref-p (3x3):', 
     '      ref-p[    0]={ 1.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00}', 
     '      ref-p[    1]={ 0.00000e+00,  1.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00}', 
     '      ref-p[    2]={ 0.00000e+00,  0.00000e+00,  1.00000e+00}' ]

result = {'ref-p': []}
for strg in a:
    if '=' in strg:
        num_list = strg.split('=')[-1].strip('{').strip('}').split(',')
        print(num_list)
        result['ref-p'].append([float(e.strip()) for e in num_list])
print(result)
```

Output

```
[' 1.00000e+00', '  0.00000e+00', '  0.00000e+00']
[' 0.00000e+00', '  1.00000e+00', '  0.00000e+00']
[' 0.00000e+00', '  0.00000e+00', '  1.00000e+00']
{'ref-p': [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]}
```

Comment: oh god, this is perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import ast 

out = []
for index, line in enumerate(tpr_linee):
    ref = "ref-p"
    if ref in line:
        try:
            line1 = line.split('=')[1].replace('{', '(').replace('}', ')')
            line1 = ast.literal_eval(line1)
            out.append(line1)
        except:
            continue
print(out)

[(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)]
```